# No se cómo hacer un menú desplegable (select) que dependa de otro con php

Tags: php, formularios, condiciones, html-select

la cuestión es la siguiente, estoy haciendo este [formulario](https://vecy.000webhostapp.com/negocios) y tengo unos desplegables y pues a situación es la de siempre, uno  debe ser el condicional del siguiente. Eh buscado en internet pero la solución más común es agregar los datos en una base de datos y traerlos, pero pues no quiero hacerlo así porque me parece un desperdicio de tablas. Solo quiero que a través de un condicional if() al momento de elegir la categoría principal despliegue la correspondiente subcategoria.

Si alguien me puede ayudar acá dejo el código completo de lo que estoy haciendo

```
<form class="col s12" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" name="login_negocios">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h5>Información de tu negocio</h5>
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <i class="far fa-building prefix"></i>
                            <input id="name_business" type="text" name="name_business" class="validate">
                            <label for="name_business">Nombre de tu negocio</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12 xl12">
                            <i class="fas fa-map-marked prefix"></i>
                            <textarea id="address_business" type="address_business" name="address_business"  class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                            <label for="address_business">Dirección</label>
                        </div>                  

                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <p>Por favor selecciona la categoria de tu negocio</p>
                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <select name="category">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Categoria</option>
                                    <?php 
                                        foreach ($categorias as $categoria) {
                                            echo "<option value='$categoria'>$categoria</option>";
                                        } 
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                                <label>Selecciona la categoria</label>                                    
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <select name="subcategory">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>SubCategoria</option>
                                <option value="carniceria">Carniceria</option>
                                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                                    <?php 
                                        foreach ($subcategorias as $subcategoria) {
                                            echo "<option value='$subcategoria'>$subcategoria</option>";
                                        } 
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                                <label>Subcategoria</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <p>Numero de locales o sucursales</p>
                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <select name="branch_numbers">
                                    <option value="" disabled selected>Locales</option>
                                        <?php 
                                            foreach ($sucursales as $sucursal) {
                                                echo "<option value='$sucursal'>$sucursal</option>";
                                            } 
                                        ?>
                                </select>
                                <label>Selecciona la cantidad de locales</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <h5>Información de contacto</h5>


                        <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l6 xl6">
                            <i class="far fa-id-badge prefix"></i>
                            <input id="first_name" type="text" name="first_name" class="validate">
                            <label for="first_name">Nombre</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12 xl6">
                            <input id="last_name" type="text" name="last_name" class="validate">
                            <label for="last_name">Apellido</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12 xl12">
                            <i class="material-icons prefix">mail</i>
                            <input id="email" type="email" name="email" class="validate">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12 xl12">
                        <i class="far fa-id-badge prefix"></i>
                            <input id="tel" type="tel" name="tel" class="validate">
                            <label for="tel">Telefono</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <p>Selecciona tu cargo dentro del negocio</p>
                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <select name="business_role">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Cargo</option>
                                    <?php 
                                        foreach ($roles as $role) {
                                            echo "<option value='$role'>$role</option>";
                                        } 
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                                <label>Selecciona tu cargo</label>                                    
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <?php if(!empty($errores)): ?>
                        <div class="red-text col s12 m12 l12 xl12">
                            <ul>
                                <?php echo $errores; ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                       <?php endif; ?>

                       <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <p>Al enviar tus datos, aceptas los <a href="terminos">Términos y condiciones generales</a>
                             y reconoces que leíste la <a href="privacidad">Política de privacidad</a>.</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <!-- <input type="submit" value="" type="submit" class="btn red accent-4">  -->
                            <div class="col s12 m12 l12 xl12 center-align ">
                            <a onclick="login_negocios.submit()" class="btn orange z-depth-2">Enviar</a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- <button id="input_9" type="submit" class="btn red accent-4" data-component="button">
                            Enviar Correo
                            </button> -->
                        </div>



                    </div>
                </form>
```

//Aquí empieza php

```
$categorias = array('Abastos y viveres',
                'Panaderias y pastelerias',
                'Tecnología', 'Ropa y accesorios',
                'Salud y Bienestar', 'Entretenimiento y ocío',
                'Restaurante', 'Ferreterias', 'Automotriz',
                'Corte y confección', 'Academias', 
                'Postres y fruterias', 'Fotos estudios',
                'Casas comerciales (Compra y venta)', 'Papelerias',
                'variedades y regalos (Cacharrerias)', 'Lavanderias',
                'Cigarrerias', 'Utensilios desechableas', 'Remontadoras y zapaterias',
                'Deportes y tiempo libre', 'Belleza', 'Mascotas'
        );




        if ($categorias == ['Abastos y viveres']) {
            $subcategorias = array('carnicerias',
                                    'Supermercados',
                                    'Pescaderias', 'A granel',
                                    'Salsamentaria'
            );
        }
        // if ($categorias = 'Abastos y viveres') {
        //    array('carnicerias',
        // 'Supermercados',
        // 'Pescaderias', 'A granel',
        // 'Salsamentaria'
        // }
        // if ($_POST["elegido"]==1) {
        //     $html = '
        //     <option value="1">4</option>
        //     <option value="2">5</option>
        //     <option value="3">7</option>
        //     <option value="4">21</option>
        //     <option value="5">Scennic</option>
        //     <option value="6">Traffic</option>
        //     ';   
        // }
```

$sucursales = array('1 sucursal',
                    '2 sucursales',
                    '3 a 5 sucursales', 
                    '6 a 9 sucursales',
                    '10 a 20 sucursales'
            );

$roles = array('Propietario',
                'Gerente',
                'Administrador', 
                'Subgerente',
                'Coordinador',
                'Empleado',
                'Encargado',
                'Auxiliar',
                'Aseador',
                'Vigilante',
                'Cocinero',
                'Mesero',
                'Asistente',
                'Conductor',
            );

Comment: El problema es que PHP se ejecuta en el servidor, una vez que terminó su ejecución se envía el resultado al cliente que está en otra computadora. Deberías usar Javascript para hacer algo como lo que describes, y hacerlo del lado del cliente.

Comment: Asero82 Muchas gracias. y otra pregunta cual me recomiendas? 
Uso la version de php o uso javascript